# ImportXML XPath URL in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I just started using google sheets and I wonder if it is possible to fetch a link using `importxml` XPath

https://prnt.sc/orrxpv

[image: 0]

here in this screenshot, you can see the clickable link under main tournament sub-menu which will change every week. currently, I am copy-pasting it manually every week you can find it in a16 cell of the sheet linked below

https://prnt.sc/orrx4y

[image]

here is the XPath that I am trying to acquire XPath (I am a total noob at this) and trying to frame it into a formula in a14 cell but have failed miserably.

I also wonder that if it is possible to =concatenate something in between the link
for eg:

```
https://www.tennisexplorer.com/cincinnati/2019/atp-men/
https://www.tennisexplorer.com/cincinnati/2018/atp-men/
https://www.tennisexplorer.com/cincinnati/2017/atp-men/
```

I want to change the year in between the link but cannot figure how :(

Link to the sheet with edit permission :)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Y6q2tw26c-nbmqIrXiQ_ZhuDc48oAzkXvOl78kVy00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what exactly you tryin' to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create selectable year in link use:

```
="https://www.tennisexplorer.com/cincinnati/"&B1&"/atp-men/"
```

[image: 0]

---

to get Cincinety you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.tennisexplorer.com/cincinnati/2019/atp-men/", 
 "//td[@class='t-name']")), "select Col2 where Col1 is null limit 1", 0))
```

and then the whole formula would be:

```
="https://www.tennisexplorer.com/"&
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.tennisexplorer.com/live/", 
 "//td[@class='t-name']")), "select Col2 where Col1 is null limit 1", 0))&"/"&B1&"/atp-men/"
```

[image: 0]

Comment: As for the array formula some tournaments are split in two words so if it is possible just to fetch the link directly ?  https://prnt.sc/ousys2

Comment: for example i want to create 6 tabs with the live tournament pre fixed on this location(they will change every link). The clickable links on these spots. https://prnt.sc/out29t

Comment: for two-words names you can use this fix: `=SUBSTITUTE("https://www.tennisexplorer.com/"&
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTXML("https://www.tennisexplorer.com/live/", 
 "//td[@class='t-name']")), "select Col2 where Col1 is null limit 1", 0))&"/"&B1&"/atp-men/", " ", "-")`

Comment: the selectable year formula is linked to another cell which will fetch the link for eg: check cell a15 i've used "=CONCATENATE(A16, "?phase=qualification" )"

Comment: in Sheet9 I left you all formulae you need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGVEg.png - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Y6q2tw26c-nbmqIrXiQ_ZhuDc48oAzkXvOl78kVy00/edit#gid=1514873202

Comment: works like charm, thank you. one last request can you also add 'lower level tournaments' to avoid list ? check cell b21.

Comment: Thank you very much i just worked 6+ hrs on this sheet your formula opened so many doors i am just one step away from total automation. My querry is solved within 24h hats off to @player0 and stackoverflow!